# How can I pass input from a text_field as a parameter to create an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to take the input that the user enters in the text_field below and pass it as a parameter in the button_to that creates the object:

```
<%= text_field :objects, :object %>
<%= button_to("Comment!", :action => "create", :controller => "comments", :comment => {:user_id => current_user.id, :location_id=> location.id }) %>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: why? what will the problem it resolve?

Comment: It will allow me to create a Comment object

Answer (score 0):

`button_to` is not the best tool to do what you need.

You need to use a form to receive the text_field on controller. Then you will be able to create a comment object. Example:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :text %>
  <%= f.submit "Comment!" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `form_for` to create the Comment instead of `button_to`. The value of you text field will be available to your controller in `params`.